# Random variable is equal to $Z/\sqrt{U/25}$ where $Z$ = N(0,1) and U=$\chi^2(25)$. What is the probability that variable between values?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, chi-squared

**Question:** Suppose that a random variable $T$ is equal to $\frac{Z}{\sqrt{U/25}}$, where $Z$ is N(0,1) and $U$ is $\chi^2(25)$. What is the probability that this random variable takes a value between 1.708 and 2.787?

**Approach:** So $T = \frac{\overline{\chi}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ where: $\mu = 0$, $n = 25$ and $S = 1$.Then, the probability to find $T$ between the specified values is:

$P(1.78 < T < 2.787)$ $\rightarrow$ $P(\frac{1.708-0}{1/\sqrt{25}} < T < \frac{2.787-0}{1/\sqrt{25}})$ $\rightarrow$ $P(8.54 < T < 13.935)$.

I am unsure on how to proceed or even if what I did is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can conclude the distribution of T from sampling. Lets say you take a random sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution.   Therefore you have $n$ (independent) random variables ($X_i$) with the distribution $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

The unbiased estimator of the variance is $s_u^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2$. Now we can divide both sides of the equation by $\sigma^2$

$Q=\frac{s_u^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2$

This is equal to $Q=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$, where $Z_i\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

From the sample theory it is known that $s=(n-1)Q\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$

And finally we know that $\frac{Z}{s/ \sqrt n}$ is $t$-distributed as $t_{n-1}$

Hint: The result in percentage has only one decimal place.

Comment: Ok, I get what you are saying, but I don't really get how I could implement it in this problem. I think I might be overthinking this problem, and I do not know how to continue. Would you suggest tackling the problem in a different way? or am I just missing something? I would really appreciate if you could give me some more clear guidance